# JQuery: Click on div text to set input field value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to set the input field value to the text inside the option field when the user clicks on it. This will require keeping record of the last input field that was focused on, so I can later set its value when the user click on an 'option'.

Markup

```
<div class="option">apples</div>
<div class="option">oranges</div>
<div class="option">pears</div>

<input type="text" value="default" class="fruit-name"/>
<input type="text" value="default" class="fruit-name"/>
<input type="text" value="default" class="fruit-name"/>
```

JQuery (With pseudo code)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.fruit-name').click(function(){
      $('.option').click(function(){
           $((this)(fruit-name)).val($((this)(option)).text());

      });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $option = $('.option'),
        $fruit = $('.fruit-name'),
        $last;

    $fruit.focus(function() {
        $last = $(this);
    })

    $option.click(function() {
        $last.val(this.innerHTML)
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jgBxs/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks close, but does not work correctly.

Comment: The correct input field does not get set when you click on a fruit name everytime, only works in some cases. Starting from the left, in your jsfiddle, there are 3 input fields. You click on the first one, then click on 'oranges' it should set the value of the input field to oranges. If you click on the same input field again, then click 'apples', it should then set it to apples. Then if you click on the rightmost input field and then click 'pears' it should set the value to pears for THAT input field.